# work provided on site lunch event

Tags: events

The company that I work for provides a monthly lunch on work premises.  It is not mandatory but most attend.  Should hourly employees be paid for this or required to clock out and not be paid?

Comment: Are you paid for lunch hour most people are not. Do you not clock out for lunch any how?

Comment: What do you do when you go to lunch during the rest of the month?

Comment: It is mixed with hourly and salaried people attending.  Work is almost always discussed among everyone probably because it's what everyone has in common and many are available.  Many clock out for lunch and many do not on any given day.  Wondering if it is legal to make people clock out at that time, when it is a work event?  Not arguing it, just unsure.  It is questioned because a top executive con

Comment: Comes in and asks hourly employees in the middle of lunch in front of everyone if they are clocked out.  He also checks to see if they are.

Answer (score 5):

If they were paying, then it would be a work meeting.  But then in many jurisdictions, the employee would still be entitled to a lunch break after the "lunch" had finished, because the law says that people are entitled to breaks.

On the occasions when my employer offers me free food at lunch time, I don't complain that they aren't paying me to eat the free food.